# Trigger Submit Form On Click Menu Drop Down Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a drop down menu list which displays all the current languages avaible.

Question: How can I make it so when Ever I click on a  link in my language foreach loop. That it will trigger to submit the form below it.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<?php foreach($languages as $language) {?>
<li><a id="language-form"><?php echo $language['name'];?></a></li>
<form action="<?php echo base_url('admin/common/header/set_lang');?>" id="lang" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="<?php echo $language['code'];?>" />
</form>
<?php }?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AJAX to simplify this code instead of generating so many forms.

See the below code

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <?php foreach($languages as $language) {?>
    <li class="lang-item">
        <a value="<?php echo $language['code'];?>">
            <?php echo $language['name'];?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php }?>
</ul>
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.lang-item', function(){
        var value = $(this).find('a').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo base_url('admin/common/header/set_lang');?>",
            contentType: false,
            data: "lang=" + value
        }).then(function(){
            console.log('language successfully update');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What would the post name="" be `$_POST['something']`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $(this).siblings('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1st .. while ID should be unique .. try to use Classes use

```
class="language-form"
```

instead of

```
id="language-form"
```

2nd to submit a form by clicking on li

```
$('dropdown-menu li').on('click',function(){
    $(this).next('form').submit();
});
```

3rd to submit a form by clicking on anchor in li  after change Id to class

```
$('dropdown-menu li .language-form').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('li').next('form').submit();
    });
```